# An estimation problem related to a certain stochastic process (radom sum of stochastic processes)

Tags: time-series, estimation, stochastic-processes, compound-distributions, infinite-mixture-model

Let $N\sim \hbox{Poisson}(\lambda)$ and $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ be a stochastic process. Consider the following stochastic process:
$$ Y_t = \sum_{j=1}^N X_{t,j}$$
where $(X_{t,1})_{t\in \mathbb Z}, (X_{t,2})_{t\in \mathbb Z},..., (X_{t,j})_{t\in \mathbb Z},...  \overset {\mathrm{i.i.d}} \sim  (X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ and independent of $N$.

Note that this process is not the [Compound Poisson Process](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_process). This is just a process such that $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ has a compound Poisson infinite dimensional distribution, according with [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Compound_Poisson_distribution), but instead of compound random variables, we compound stochastic process.

Some results that may be useful:

1. If $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is strictly stationary processes, then $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is strictly stationary processes. Moreover, denoting $\mu_X^k:= E[X_t^k]$ (by statinarity, for all $t$), we have $\mu_Y = \lambda \mu_X $. If $\mu_X=0$, then:
   $$\mu_Y = \lambda\, \mu_X =0$$
   $$\mu_Y^2 = \lambda \, \mu_X^2, \quad \mu_Y^3 = \lambda \, \mu_X^3\quad \hbox{for all }t$$
2. If $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$  is such that $\mu_X=0$ and $\gamma_X(k)$ is its autocorrelation function, we have:
   $$\gamma_Y(k)= \lambda \gamma_X(k)$$
   See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4581620/a-question-about-an-autocorrelation-function-of-a-stochastic-process).
3. If $(X_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$ is mean-ergodic stochastic process, then we can show that
   $$
   \frac 1T\sum_{t=1}^T Y_{t} \overset{pr}{\longrightarrow} N\mu_X\quad (T\to\infty).
   $$
   So, if $\mu_X =0$, we have that $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$  is mean ergodic. See [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4536534/is-a-compound-poisson-sum-of-ergodic-processes-an-ergodic-process).
4. By an argument analogous to the previous item, we can show that if $\mu_X=0$ and $(X_{t})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ is ergodic for the second moments, then
   $$ \frac{1}{T-k} \sum_{t=k+1}^T Y_t Y_{t-k} \overset{pr}{\longrightarrow}  N \gamma_X(k), \quad (\forall \, k , T\to\infty)$$
   So, $(Y_{t})_{t\in \mathbb Z}$ is **not** ergodic for the second moments (To be ergodic for the second moments, the above convergence would have to be for $\lambda \gamma_X(k)$. See second item).

Now, I'd like to estimate $\lambda$, for the case:
$$\mu_X = 0.$$
and the case I have only one realization of $(Y_t)_{t \in \mathbb Z}$.

But I'm having some difficulties. I tried the method of moments, but naturally other parameters came up that I'm not interested at first. Given a realization $(y_t)_{t=1}^T$

$$\frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_t^2 = \lambda\mu_X^2, \quad \frac{1}{T}\sum_{t=1}^T y_t^3 = \lambda\mu_X^3, ...$$

I believe it is an identification problem, as I have more parameters than moment conditions. Furthermore, even if we had some kind of identification, perhaps due to non-ergodicity, our GMM estimator would not be consistent (I know almost nothing about GMM, sorry for any absurd statements).

So, I would like your help to indicate a way to solve my problem of estimating $\lambda$.
Even if for that I have to estimate more parameters. Any tips?

**Updates based on comments**

1. Yves' comment made me see something I hadn't noticed before. Given that I have only one realization of $(Y_t)$, consequently I have only one realization of $N$, as this one does not depend on $t$. This is bad. Given this, I came up with a vague idea of using the Bootstrap technique. Would this be adequate? (Again, sorry for any nonsense I may speak)
2. Here we have a simulation in R language (I don't observe anything about $(X_t)$. I just observe one realization of $(Y_t)$):

```
## Simultaing Y with lambda= 5

#-------------generate data-------------
set.seed(123)

# Size of my unique realization
T <- 1000

# N ~ Poisson(lambda)
lambda = 5
N  = rpois(1, lambda )

# Create an Empty DataFrame with T rows and N columns. I will agregate to get y
A = matrix(nrow = T , ncol = N)

for (j in 1:N)
{
  aux = arima.sim(model = list(ar = 0.9), n = T )
  for (t in 1:T)
  {
    A[t,j]<-aux[t]
  }
}

# Agregating 
y = ts(rowSums(A))

# Plot
plot(y)
```

[image]

Comment: Since $N$ does not depend on $t$ a realization $(y_t)_t$ corresponds to *one* realization of $N$ hence you can not estimate $\lambda$ beyond the trivial $\hat{\lambda} = \hat{N}$. If you have several realizations corresponding to i.i.d. $N_i$ then you could infer on $\lambda$. Since the stochastic process is only partially specified, you could find $\hat{N}_i$ from 3, then $\hat{\lambda}$ by averaging.

Comment: Maybe I can't use 3 because I forgot to say that I have $\mu_X=0$.

Comment: If you have several realizations then you can first estimate the $N_i$ using the moments and then estimate $\lambda$. For instance (special case $k=0$ in 4.) the variance of realization $i$ is $N_i$ times the variance of $X$. If you have a parametric model for the stochastic process $(X_t)_t$ then you could use Expectation Maximization $N_i$ as latent variables or a Bayesian inference.

Comment: I have only one realization of $(Y_t)$. Perhaps something more parsimonious would be to assume that $(X_t)$ is an $AR(1)$, but it could be something else, for example a strictly stationary ARIMA (This just adds more parameters to be estimated.).    I put one more update. I would like to understand more about Expectation Maximization.

Comment: Actually, I didn't want to assume anything about $(X_t)$ because I don't observe anything about $(X_t)$. I just observe one realization of $(Y_t)$.